# asp.net session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

how do i set the session timeout in asp.net ?

thru the code and thru the web.config (i heard that you can do it here).

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes In your web.config

```
<sessionState
mode="InProc"
stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
cookieless="false"
timeout="30"
/>
```

Maintains session state for 30 mins

Answer (score 1):

To do it via web.config:

Modify the timeout attribute of the sessionState element.

```
<sessionState timeout="30" />
```

To do it in code:

```
Session.Timeout = 20;
```

Easy peasy. :)